# Pass a nested array to the params argument inside Craft's url() function

Tags: url, array

I have a list of checkboxes in a GET form which results in a URL with a querystring like `?q=&cat=&city%5B%5D=28&city%5B%5D=26&sort=asc&order=name` when submitted. The Object/Array behind this string looks like:

```
Array
(
    [q] => 
    [cat] => 
    [city] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28
            [1] => 26
        )
    [sort] => asc
    [order] => name
)
```

I'm trying to create a link with one of those GET params changed, but I can't find a way to update a single value. So now I'm rebuilding the URL by creating an object based on the given query params.

If I pass this object (as shown above) to the second argument inside Craft's [`url()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/functions#url) function to use this URL on a simple `<a>` tag, I get an `Array to string conversion` error.

I seems Craft can't handle nested arrays in this function. Is there another method to generate an URL from such an object?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, looks like Craft's [`url()`](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/functions#url) method doesn't support nested array syntax for querystring params.

If you still want to use it, then you'd need to flatten it with unique keys such as:

```
Array
(
    [q] => 
    [cat] => 
    [city0] => 28
    [city1] => 26
    [sort] => asc
    [order] => name
)
```

Alternatively you can manually build the URL yourself in Twig in whatever format you'd like.